# deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have been struggle to get this query up and running but keep on running into dead ends, I have read through quite a few forums but I cannot find a solution for my issue.
My initial error was table mutation error and I understand that oracle is still busy with the table and therefore could not perform my 2nd task. Basically I have a table called project_tbl and another table which is a copy of this table called proj_archive_tbl. My logic is, when the column in project_tbl called proj_status change to completed, it must insert the whole row into proj_archive_tbl and than change the column deleted_status in project_tbl to 'X'.

My 1st attempt was a trigger that perform and insert into proj_archive_tbl and than update the project_tbl delete_status = 'X' but I get mutation error.

Now I have create 2 triggers, one to copy data to archive table when status change to completed on project table and the other trigger, when new row is inserted into proj_archive_tbl, update project delete_status to 'X' but get the "deadlock detected while waiting for resource". I have tried created a package with array but I struggle since I am a newbie with oracle and have also attempted to follow asktom recommendations, compound triggers and antonomous_transactions but all to no avail. Here is the code if anyone can please help me or direct me in the right way it will be greatly appreciated:

```
create or replace 
trigger Arch_Proj_trigger
    after update of proj_status on project_tbl
    for each row
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
if upper(:new.proj_status) = UPPER('completed') then
    insert into proj_archive_tbl 
        values (
          :old.proj_code,
          :old.proj_name,
          :old.cust_code,
          :old.proj_manager,
          :old.start_date,
          :old.end_date,
          :old.max_budget,
          :new.proj_status,
          :old.delete_status);
end if;
commit;
```

### end;

```
create or replace 
trigger Mark_Proj_Deleted
after insert on proj_archive_tbl
for each row
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
    update project_tbl set delete_status = 'X' 
    where proj_code = :new.proj_code;
commit;
```

### end;

I hope I am using the correct forum and that sufficient information was supplied.
Please help!
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach isn't going to work. Here's what's happening to cause the deadlock:

1. When you update a row in `project_tbl`, your transaction will obtain a row lock and apply the changes
2. Your trigger `arch_proj_trigger` is then firing after the update and is inserting a row into the table `proj_archive_tbl`
3. The insert into the `proj_archive_tbl` table causes the trigger `mark_proj_deleted` to fire - this cannot update the row in `project_tbl` because the original transaction is still holding its row lock from when you updated the status
4. The first trigger cannot complete until the second one completes - but the second one will never complete because the originating update statement is blocking it.

I'm generally not an advocate of having this kind of application logic in triggers - for the reason illustrated above and others. Generally speaking if you start to hit deadlock or mutation issues, the approach is wrong.

My advice is to use a PL/SQL procedure to perform this type of data manipulation and disallow direct update statements against the table. At least that way, you implement the controls you require and everything is a lot simpler and (more importantly) transactionally sound.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is for an academic assignment and the requirements are that we need to create 5 triggers. I thought this would be a good trigger but having too much trouble with it. Will discard and make use of procedures :)

Comment: If you want to get your trigger count up, you could theoretically still use a trigger to copy the updated row into the proj_archive_tbl table.